# How can I convert an array of numbers to strings?

Tags: javascript, tostring, array.prototype.map

I can't convert array's numbers into strings. What is wrong with my code?

I also tried: `this.userIds.toString().split(',')`

```js
collectIds() {
  this.array.forEach((e, i) => {
    // [8, 8, 8, undefined, undefined, undefined]
    if (this.array[i].details.user_id !== undefined) {
      this.userIds.push(this.array[i].details.user_id)
      // [8, 8, 8]
    }
  });
  
  this.userIds.map(e => e.toString())
  console.log("userIds: ", this.userIds)
  // [8, 8, 8]
}
```

Comment: Please add an array to the snippet demo above so we can see the output.

Comment: Your demo code has an error and there is no sample data

Comment: `this.userIds = this.array.filter( x => x!== undefined).map(x => x.toString());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates a new array with the transformed elements. It does not modify the old one.

You could reassign `this.userIds` to the new array.

```js
this.userIds = this.userIds.map(e => e.toString());
```

Or you could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and mutate the array while iterating.

```js
this.userIds.forEach((e, i, a) => a[i] = e.toString());
```

Comment: I used forEach method, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new array.

You will need to reassign `this.userIds` if this is your intention.

```js
this.userIds = this.userIds.map(e => e.toString())
```